# Trouble getting Finale and Cakewalk to agree on midi file tempo

Tags: midi, tempo, sequencer

I have a score I have created in Finale.  I'm working on creating an audio sample of it.  Some parts of it (the strings) sound good using the sound libraries within Finale but other parts (the chorus) sound best when I can edit them in a DAW.  I am using Cakewalk for this.

I exported the audio I want from finale for the strings and then exported the voice parts in .mid format from finale, intending to use Cakewalk to render the voices.

My trouble is that I can't seem to get finale and Cakewalk to agree on tempo.  Tempo information doesn't seem to exist in the finale midi output, or if it does it is ignored by Cakewalk.   I also tried exporting a tempo map midi but can't figure out to import this into Cakewalk.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself because I figured it out.  I imported the midi file in question unto finale and the time signatures and tempo were preserved.   Thus the problem is that Cakewalk doesn't read midi tempo data (unless it is deeply buried somewhere and also not included in the documentation.   Solution was to use Reaper instead.